# Como faço para cada palavra de uma frase fique com o inicio maiúsculo?

Tags: php

Eu queria que meu campo nome ficasse cada parte maiúsculo ex: usuário coloca "jose santos" queria inserir no mysql "Jose Santos"

Comment: Obrigado Andrei, mais eu consegui usando a função mb_convert_case, ai consegui adicionar exceção de palavras como 'de' 'do'... mais mesmo assim muito obrigado pela boa vontade

Comment: Eu acho que era o sono, mas a sua pergunta estava duplicada mesmo. kkkk

Comment: Tranquilo Woopring! Que bom que resolveu.